# ActiveX component cannot create Sage Data Object

Tags: vba, object, activex, tlbimp, sage50

I'm using some slightly amended VBA code provided by Sage to connect to Sage 50 Accounts - this works on some machines, but not with others, despite them all having the same version of Sage (25.1.128), and has previously worked on all machines without issue. The error specifically occurs when attempting to instantiate the Sage Data Object, where i get *'Run-time error ' 429': ActiveX component can't create object'*.

I've tried reinstalling Sage on one of the problem machines and checked the correct references are added to the VBA project. All machines in question are running windows 10 64 bit. This is the connection code I'm using:

```
Sub SageConnectTest()

Dim oSDO As SageDataObject250.SDOEngine
Dim oWS As SageDataObject250.WorkSpace
Dim oSdc As Object, oSrs As Object
Dim szDataPath As String

Set oSDO = New SageDataObject250.SDOEngine
Set oWS = oSDO.Workspaces.Add("Example")

szDataPath = oSDO.SelectCompany("C:\ProgramData\Sage\Accounts\2019")

If szDataPath <> "" Then
    ' Try to Connect - Will Throw an Exception if it Fails
    If oWS.Connect(szDataPath, XXXX, XXXX, XXXX) Then
        MsgBox "Connection to Sage is Successful!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sage Connection Test"
    End If
End If

If oSDO.isregistered = True Then
    MsgBox "Sage Data Object is Registered", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Sage Connection Test"
    Else
    MsgBox "SDO registration Faliure", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Sage Connection Test"
End If

oWS.Disconnect

Exit Sub
Errhandle:
oWS.Disconnect
MsgBox "There was an error connecting to Sage - disconnecting", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Sage Connection Test"

End Sub
```

Googling the problem found a few results that point to a tlb file called 'SdoENG250.tlb' - I've verified that the file is located on the problem machines, but I believe it may need to be registered and I'm not sure how to do that, or even check to see if it is registered. I'm don't even know if that's the source of the problem at this point.

Comment: are you using the 64-bit version of Office (not windows)? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office#activex-control-and-com-add-in-compatibility

Comment: Ah! 64-bit on the machines with the problem but 32-bit on the machine that works. I bet that's it but I'll do some checking just in case...

Comment: The issue does appear to be with the 64-bit version of office - the dll in question appears to be 32-bit so I'm trying to source an alternate version of it now. Thanks to @L8n, feel free to add this as the answer and I'll credit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the 64-bit Version of **Office** (not Windows!) you need the appropriate Version of the external library. If you wrote it yourself, generate a 64-bit version, if it comes from a vendor, consider asking them for a new version [MS Docs: Compatibility between the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/compatibility-between-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office#activex-control-and-com-add-in-compatibility) .

It seems Sage offers a 64-bit Version of their Add-Ins/Tools, albeit with limited functionality:
[Microsoft Office and Sage Accounts, Payroll, HR and Forecasting compatibility](https://my.sage.co.uk/public/help/askarticle.aspx?articleid=32017)
[Sage 50 Accounts: Install the 64-bit ODBC driver](https://ask.sage.co.uk/scripts/ask.cfg/php.exe/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=35159)

Comment: Thanks for the links L8n - I'm in contact with sage to see if they provide a 64bit version of the Sage Data Objects. So far they've suggested installing the 64 bit ODBC drivers but we already have those installed so I've gone back to them and am awaiting an answer. If I get anything conclusive out of all this back an forth I'll update this post for info.